# Facebook application disabled due to suspected phishing activity. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: php, facebook, redirect

New applications need to use OAuth 2.0

I used the code from this blog for authentication:
http://kartiklad.com/

```
 $redirect_url = 'http://url-of-site-for-canvas-app.com/authorize/';
     $oauth_url    = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=' . $client_id . '&redirect_uri=' . $redirect_url . '&type=user_agent&&display=' . $display . '&scope=' . $scope;
```

I created a folder called authorize and redirected the user here to exchange the session token. Then once the 'code' parameter is not empty the app code starts getting executed.

The thing is that the above code in the blog worked like a charm. My app almost got to the point where it could have gone viral. Almost 100 new users everyday and suddenly I get this notice saying it is suspected of phishing activity.

This is the official link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

NOTE: My app asks for user permission in the beginning and once the user logs in the result gets displayed automatically on his wall and a photo gets uploaded into the photo album. I asked for all the necessary permissions before the user got into my app. Maybe this has something to do with it? I saw another popular app doing this with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks to be correct in your setup and seeing that it follows basically the same scheme as Facebook has listed on there developers site, I do not see where it could have gone wrong. There must have been users who reported the application or maybe Facebook's system to check the applications has a bug that caused your application to be suspended.

Unless Facebook gives you a better reason then listed above, I'd contact them to see the real reason why it was suspended. It could have been malicious users reporting your application. If you truly have legit code and don't see where you could have gone wrong, your best bet is to ask the source of the problem, Facebook. Hopefully they will be able to clarify for you.